# Using Chromedriver with Google Images download

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-image-search

I am trying to run the following code to pull in some images:

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download   #importing the library

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()   #class instantiation

arguments = {"keywords":"foxes, shiba inu outside","limit":2000,"print_urls":True}   #creating list of arguments
paths = response.download(arguments)   #passing the arguments to the function
print(paths)   #printing absolute paths of the downloaded images
```

Because I am trying to do over 100 images I am getting a message saying

> Looks like we cannot locate the path the 'chromedriver' (use the '--chromedriver' argument to specify the path to the executable.) or google chrome browser is not installed on your machine (exception: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType)

I am unsure how to integrate the chromedriver piece into my code and set the path.  I searched around but I cannot find a clear answer.  I tried adding the line

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/jerelnovick/Desktop/Projects/Image_Recognition/chromedriver.exe")
```

as I read in one post but that gave me a message saying

> WebDriverException: Message: 'Image_Recognitionchromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some additional steps to take to get more than 100 images. From the [docs](https://google-images-download.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#installing-the-chromedriver-with-selenium):

> If you would want to download more than 100 images per keyword, then you will need to install ‘selenium’ library along with ‘chromedriver’ extension.

And then your `arguments` will need to be updated as:

```py
arguments = {"keywords":"foxes, shiba inu outside",
             "limit":2000,
             "print_urls":True,
             "chromedriver":"/Users/jerelnovick/Desktop/Projects/Image_Recognition/chromedriver"}
```

Also make sure the chromedriver you download is the proper one for mac.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then hardcode line 177 of google_images_download.py where it says browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chromeoptions=options) and set the chromedriver variable to the absolute path such as "C:/Users\YourUserName\Desktop\google-images-download-master\google_images_download\chromedriver.exe"

Comment: MyNameIsCaleb's response is working perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jerel glad it is working. Please hit the checkmark next to my answer. :)